# Socket/Threads (Cliente/Servidor) Java

Tags: java, thread, socket

Estou com uma duvida muito cruel.Pesquisei muito e não achei nada parecido para resolver meu caso.

O que preciso é o seguinte:

> - O lado Cliente envia numero de cartão e valor de compra
> - O lado servidor recebe esses dados e consulta no banco de dados se o numero existe e se o saldo é suficiente.
> - Caso estiver ok o lado Servidor envia para o Cliente mensagem para informar a senha do cartão.
> - O servidor novamente recebe a informação e consulta no banco se a senha está ok e devolve a mensagem de sucesso ou de erro.

Alguém pode me dar uma ideia de como fazer isso ou tem algum exemplo parecido com isso ?

Servidor :

```
public class Servidor extends Thread{
  private Socket socket; //O socket da conexão com o cliente

  public Servidor(Socket socket)
  {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      //Obtém os streams de entrada e saída
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

      double cartao = in.readDouble(); 
      double valor = in.readDouble(); 

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
      System.err.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

  }
}
```

Main (Servidor)

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
     try
     {
       ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345); //Cria um server socket para aguardar requisições dos clientes
       while(true)
       {
         System.out.println("Aguardando conexões...");
         Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); //Fica aguardando pedidos de conexão
         System.out.println("Conectou-se...");
         (new Servidor(socket)).start(); //Inicia a thread que tratará do cliente
       }
     }
     catch (IOException ex)
     {
       System.err.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
     }
   }
}
```

Cliente :

```
public class Cliente extends Thread
{
  private String ip; //O IP do servidor
  private int porta; //A porta de comunicação que será utilizada

  public Cliente(String ip, int porta)
  {
    this.ip = ip;
    this.porta = porta;
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println("** Pagamento On Line **");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Informe o numero do cartão: ");
      double cartao = input.nextDouble(); 
      System.out.print("Informe o valor da compra: ");
      double valor = input.nextDouble(); 

      Socket socket = new Socket(ip, porta); //Conecta-se ao servidor
      //Obtém os streams de entrada e saída
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      out.writeDouble(cartao); 
      out.flush(); //Força o envio

      out.writeDouble(valor); 
      out.flush();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      System.err.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Main (Cliente)

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      //Cria o cliente para se conectar ao servidor no IP 127.0.0.1 e porta 12345
      Cliente cliente = new Cliente("127.0.0.1", 12345);
      cliente.start(); //Coloca a thread do cliente para ser executada
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz um exercício desses final do ano passado. Você não está especificando se poderá ter vários clientes conectados ao mesmo tempo, mas se tiver. Pode do servidor uma extensão para a `thread`.

```
public class Server{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12345);
        Socket cli = null;

        // sempre que um novo cliente se conectar ao
        // sistema, uma nova thread será criada
        while(1){
            boolean on = true;
            cli = ss.accept();

            while(on){
                /*Entradas, Saídas e condições dentro do while*/
                /*...*/
            }
            cli.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ola Brumazzi, não é necessário ter vários clientes ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: fiz a alteração para um usuário. se não estiver muito explicativo da uma olhada nesse link: https://github.com/brumazzi/Sistema_Bancario

Comment: Brumazzi, vou dar uma olhada mais tarde e te dou um retorno.
Muito obrigado pela ajuda cara.

Comment: Brumazzi D.B. seu sistema ficou show de bola, me ajudou muito a entender os processos entre cliente/servidor.Muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu precisei focar bastante na legibilidade porque tinha que explicar o código, kkkkkkkk

Comment: Ficou incrível cara, muito didático. Parabéns e obrigado de novo.